# regular expression to match files ending with same extention

Tags: regex, file, notepad++

I have many lines like this in a sql file

> VALUES (12654, 'somestuff', 'some
>   description here', 'filename.swf',
>   '5', 0, 1, '', '500', '300',
>   'filename.png', '3', '1');

I want somthing to find *filename.swf* and replace them with *folder/filename.swf* and then do the same the same for png files

I have very basic knowledge, tried to start from swf & go back to the Apostrophe before the filename , I think the following code does the contrary:

```
\'.*swf
```

It starts from the 1st Apostrophe in the line & ends with swf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude apostrophes from the "any-character" bit. If Notepad++ uses PCREs, I believe it would be:

```
\'[^']*swf
```

Comment: Cool that worked! I did it this way:

Find: \'([^']*swf) Replace with: 'folder/\1

Thanks for the fast response!